# Problem on a simple sampling plan

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation, sampling

Suppose I have a finite population of size $N>1$ with units $U_1,U_2,...,U_n$.
Now, I have this sampling plan:

(1)either the sample consists of only one unit $U_j$ with probability $\frac{1}{N+1}$ for any $j=1,2,...,N $

(2) or,
it consists of the whole population with probability $\frac{1}{N+1}$

Find the expected sample size.

Now, I assumed $X$ be the number of units taken.

See that $P(X=N)=\frac{1}{N+1}$ and also, $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{N+1}$ .But $X$ is supposed to follow Bernoulli distribution but infact here it is not a pmf.
I have a doubt whether $P(X=1)=\frac{N}{N+1}$?
Help!

Comment: I believe you will need $P(X=1)=\frac{N}{N+1}$ as stated.

Comment: But what is the logic?

Comment: Well X can take 2 values. Either $N$ or $1$. By definition of a pmf, $\sum P(X)=1$. Also $P(X=N)=\frac 1{N+1} \implies P(X=1)=1-\frac 1{N+1}=\frac N{N+1}$.

Comment: Yes, I know that but look at the question..it clearly states that $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{N+1}$, so how will it be a pmf?

Comment: Well then the question cannot be correct. The probability of the measure space must sum to $1$. Have you written that $P(X=1)= \frac 1{N+1}$ or is it part of a homework question?

Comment: It is from a test .. and they haven't given any correction

Answer (score 1):

Okay first, we define $X$ as the number of units selected. We know that according to the sampling plan, we can either select **exactly** $1$ unit *OR* every unit, i.e. $N$ units. From the $(2)$, $$P(X=N)= \frac 1{N+1}$$ Since by definition of a probability distribution, $$P(X=N)+P(X=1)=1$$ Hence $$P(X=1)=1-P(X=N)=1-\frac 1{N+1}=\frac {N+1}{N+1}-\frac 1{N+1}=\frac N{N+1}$$

Now by definition of an expectation,
$$E(X)=\sum_x xP(X=x)=1\cdot P(X=1)+N\cdot P(X=N)$$
$$=1\cdot \frac N{N+1}+N\cdot \frac 1{N+1}=\frac {2N}{N+1}$$

Lets also consider what happens when $N$ is large, i.e. asymptotics:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}E(X)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {2N}{N+1}=2$$

Does that make sense?